# Getting an image in Base64 format as global variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get image in Base64 format outside of

```
var codedPic;
var purl = 'http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/4a/Logo_2013_Google.png';

var codedPic = convertImgToBase64(purl, function(base64Img){ console.log('attempt 1: ' + base64Img); });

console.log('attempt 2: ' + codedPic);
```

It is getting results of attempt 1 but for attempt 2 it displays undefined. But I need it working too. Can anyone help me please?

Please feel free to amend this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/s7x0otdc/2/

Answer (score 0):

(in fiddle) after you complete the conversion, you call callback, therefore nothing is stored in codedPic variable.
you can fix it by using `return codedPic;` instead of using callback
or you can do everything you need in that callback function (because after completing callback function you lose "hers" variables)

i suppose there is some way with global vars.. but just now i don't know how i would do that

Comment: thank you is any example on my jsfiddle you can do please?

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

New demo to show you how to modularize your code. The encoded picture **is** available outside of your conversion function (more precisely in your global variable `codedPic`). But you have to wait for your callback to be triggered to be sure it now has the correct value.

http://jsfiddle.net/s7x0otdc/7/

---

Well you have several mistakes in your code.

1. As pointed out by Jimmmy, your function does not return anything, so the assignment `var codedPic = convertImgToBase64(purl /* ... */ );` is useless as codedPic will remain `undefined`.
2. Time to read [How to return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call) to understand why you need to use callbacks, and that you have to put any code that depends on a server response inside a callback. Since your conversion function needs to wait for the `load` event of your image, you will get data into `dataURL` at an unkown moment in the future. When this moment arrives, JS will trigger your callback and give it that data as argument, as per your conversion function specifies. So only your callback can safely assign your desired data into a global variable, and trigger any action that depend on that data.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/s7x0otdc/5/

Comment: Thank you but is there any way to get base64Img value outside of codedPic finction???

Comment: Well it **is** available outside of the **`convertImgToBase64`** function, and assigned to `codedPic` variable… The problem is **when** the value is correct. Only once your callback is triggered you know you can safely use what is inside `codedPic`. So the idea is to call anything that depends on that value, from that callback. Let me update the jsfiddle to show you how you could use functions to get modularity.